# How can I remove the time from Moment.JS date?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm doing the following to get the date however it always has the time how can I remove it?

```
return moment(this.organicFieldStatusTo, "MM-DD-YYYY", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll plagiarise better:

```
return moment.utc(dateTime).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
```

Comment: The return type in the OP is `Moment`, while the return type in your answer is `string`.